# Mutate after Fetch using React-Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have some condition to check before update the data

```
    const {data, status} = useTask(['task', {id: 1}]);
    const {mutate} = useSaveTask(['task', {id: 1}], {
      onMutate: (payload) => queryClient.setQueryData(['task', {id: 1}], (oldData) => ({...oldData.data, status: payload.status}));
    });
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if (status === 'success' && data.data.status == 'waiting') {
        mutate({ status: 'processing'});
      }
    }, [data, status, mutate]);
```

But my page always got infinite loop. Thanks for any hint

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You do have an infinite loop in there. You have a query that returns `data` and a mutation that, `onMutate`, modifies the query data using `setQueryData`. This means that every time you run the mutation by calling `mutate()` it also modifies the `data` returned from the query.

```
useEffect(() => {
    ...
}, [data, status, mutate]);
```

So finally, when we get to the dependency array of `useEffect`, it fires every time `data` change. And you enter a loop:

`data` change -> call `mutate` -> modify `data` in `onMutate` -> `data` change -> call `mutate` -> modify `data` in `onMutate`